# How can i run test with selenium web driver on linux, using geckodriver?

Tags: java, linux, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I have an project, that works correctly with a chrome webdriver on Windows OS, and Linux OS. I added support geckodriver on windows and it's works fine. But i can't add support geckodriver on linux for my java-selenium autotests purpose.

My setup is:

OS: Fedora Linux 36 (Workstation Edition) x86_64

Firefox Browser 106.0.1 (64 bits) in the /usr/bin/firefox directory. I know it because of this command:

```
[bans@bans-note ~]$ which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
```

And it is really there:

```
[bans@bans-note ~]$ ls /usr/bin |grep firefox
firefox
```

And browser is executable. After this command browser has been started

```
[bans@bans-note bin]$ ./firefox
```

This is the place in the code where i prepare driver for my tests:

```
case "linux_firefox":{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", PATH_LINUX_FIREFOX_DRIVER);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", PATH_LINUX_FIREFOX);
    FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
    firefoxOptions.addArguments("--headless");
    firefoxOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    break;
}
```

PATH_LINUX_FIREFOX_DRIVER - constant where i has stored the path to geckodriver. Gecodriver is there.

PATH_LINUX_FIREFOX - constant where i has stored the path to firfox. Firefox binary is there.

When I run the test with the setup on linux and firefox(gecko), I get an error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Specified firefox binary location does not exist or is not a real file: /usr/bin/firefox

    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:504)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Executable.<init>(Executable.java:43)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:123)
    at common.CommonActions.createDriver(CommonActions.java:65)
    at tests.base.BaseTest.<init>(BaseTest.java:15)
    at tests.TestLogin.positive.LoginTest.<init>(LoginTest.java:12)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Please help me run my tests with geckodriver!

1. ```
   case "linux_firefox":{

                   FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
                   options.setBinary(new FirefoxBinary(new  File(PATH_LINUX_FIREFOX)));
                   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                   capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxOptions.FIREFOX_OPTIONS, options);
                   capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
                   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", PATH_LINUX_FIREFOX_DRIVER);
                   driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

                   break;
   }
   ```
2. I was reinstalling the browser.
3. I installed firefox snap version.

Comment: Print the `PATH_LINUX_FIREFOX` and double check it's correct. Might also be `PATH_LINUX_FIREFOX_DRIVER`, but the former seems more likely to me.

Comment: i tried to use path, but:
'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LINUX
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'bans-note', ip: '192.168.100.16', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.19.16-200.fc36.x86_64', java.version: '18.0.2.1'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver'